# Android Google Maps Fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have created a new Android project with a Google Map activity defined as

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements   OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

The Layout is this

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.alewe.myapplication.MapsActivity" />
```

The problem is :
i have created another activity and im trying to add the google map fragment inside it.

Using the

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.firstLayout,this,this.getTag());
```

doesnt work because i cant cast FragmentActivity to Fragment.

How can i add the google maps fragment just created inside another activity ?
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just create another instance of SupportMapFrament for the other Activity?

Comment: If i do this can i put more fragment in the new activity i create ?

Comment: There are applications which consist of ten Fragments, all shown in one Activity. As you can imagine, not all of them at once. But it's possible to show several Fragments simultaneously. You have to give a certain part of the Activity Layout to one Fragment and another part to the next one [Useful link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)

Comment: Thanks. If i use SupportMapFrament for the other activity how can i choose the layout in which insert the fragment ?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you there but it sounds like you want to transfer a Fragment from one Activity to the next. Just don't ever do this, it may technically be possible (we are after all writing Java code), but it is an absolute no-go from an android point of view. Simply create (Views and) Fragments where you want to use them.

Comment: Just in case I really misunderstood: you tell the FragmentManager where to put the Fragment for example by handing it the layout id of the container where the Fragment should go (One often uses a FrameLayout as container) Like in the line with `replace(R.id.firstLayout,...)`

Answer (score 0):

Change your layout (activity_maps) like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="com.example.alewe.myapplication.MapsActivity"
  android:id="@+id/main_view_map">

  <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
      android:id="@+id/button"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:elevation="10dp"
      app:fabSize="mini"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_refresh_black_24dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" />

  <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And don't use

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.firstLayout,this,this.getTag());
```

this code.